# android: how to register my app as "camera app"

Tags: android

I was wondering how to tell android that my app is a camera app, so other apps know that they can start my app to get a picture.
E.g. with pixlr-o-matic you can either select an image from the gallery or you can request it from a camera app of your choice.

edit: 
how do i return the picture to the calling app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done with intent-filters. Add the following tag to your manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".CameraActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now your application will appear in the list when the user wants to take a picture.

**EDIT :**

Here is the proper way to return a bitmap :

```
Uri saveUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);

if (saveUri != null)
{
    // Save the bitmap to the specified URI (use a try/catch block)
    outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(saveUri);
    outputStream.write(data); // write your bitmap here
    outputStream.close();
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
}
else
{
    // If the intent doesn't contain an URI, send the bitmap as a Parcelable
    // (it is a good idea to reduce its size to ~50k pixels before)
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent("inline-data").putExtra("data", bitmap));
}
```

You can also check the android built-in [Camera app source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/camera/Camera.java#Camera.createCaptureBitmap%28byte%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Isn't there an issue with putting big images into Extras? Wouldn't it be better to return the path to the image?

Comment: How do I know that my app was called by another app? And where do I put your code (returning the bitmap)?

Comment: @Dalmas, when I open my Camera app from Contact, it will send URI(outputPath=/my_cache/ContactPhoto-IMG_20170412_094751.jpg) of it's cache directory which is private directory for Contact app, and in that case I am unable to save image on that path(Contact's private directory -- outputPath=/my_cache/ContactPhoto-IMG_20170412_094751.jpg), please help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: @Dalmas, please check below for more detail     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362604/register-my-app-as-camera-app-in-android

Answer (score 3):

You should specify an Intent filter to your Activity, that will specify that your app can be started to take a picture.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps!