# Issue in registering app as camera app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am registering my app as camera app taking help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554600/android-how-to-register-my-app-as-camera-app)

When I test the app on my phone by making an apk, the app doesn't shows in the list of apps but is available as an option on camera launch. I want the app to show both in the list of apps and also when I select camera. Will this happen when I will publish the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two `<intent-filter>` elements on your `<activity>`. One would be what you have now (`IMAGE_CAPTURE`). The other would be the standard `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` that most apps start off with, and that you probably replaced.