# Register my app as camera app in Android

Tags: android

I got help from [android: how to register my app as "camera app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554600/android-how-to-register-my-app-as-camera-app) but still it's not properly working

I have tried with my **Contact App** to add photo to my existing saved Contact, whom URI will be generated like below

```
content://com.google.android.contacts.files/my_cache/ContactPhoto-IMG_20170412_123034.jpg
```

but I can not access to that Contact app's directory, so I can not save photo over that URI and if I do I will get `FIleNotFoundException`,

```
Uri saveUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);

if (saveUri != null)
{
    // Save the bitmap to the specified URI (use a try/catch block)
    outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(saveUri); <-----File Not Found Exception
```

Menifest is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <activity
            android:name=".CameraSelfieActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_chooser_selfie"
            android:label="My Camera"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Logcat is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /my_cache/ContactPhoto-IMG_20170417_205819.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
    at com.example.CameraSelfieBaseHelper.copyFileToUri(CameraSelfieBaseHelper.java:391)
    at com.example.CameraSelfieBaseHelper.processImageReady(CameraSelfieBaseHelper.java:364)
    at com.example.CameraSelfieBaseHelper.onImageReady(CameraSelfieBaseHelper.java:266)
    at com.example.captureImage(CmGLSV.java:50)
    at com.example.surface.CmGLSV.onDrawFrame(CmGLSV.java:135)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
```

but same **functionality is achieved by default Camera App**

will anybody has suggestion how to resolve this issue

Thanks,

Comment: Where is that `Uri` value coming from?

Comment: A stacktrace would be nice to read.

Comment: I have opened my Contact app, in that I want to  add new photo to my one Contact so from that I have opened my Camera and I got Uri like above

Comment: @tynn, i will try my best to add stacktrace, but you can think the exception will come because we are saving an image to other app (here contact app)'s private directory right

Comment: we are saving an image to com.google.android.contacts.files's private directory which is my_cache, I think it will not be accessible by other app

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your app does not have the required security privileges to directly override the file (contact photo) that is externally managed by the contacts app.

What you can do to achieve the desired result is:

a. Add the necessary permissions to read/write Contacts data through the ContentResolver API

```
<uses-spermission
                android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

You can find [more information on interacting with Contacts data via the Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html)

b. Identify the ID of the contact you want to update with the new photo

c. Update the contact's photo through it's ContentResolver API

[There's this example open-source project on github that does just that](https://github.com/heinrisch/Contact-Picture-Sync/blob/master/src/heinrisch/contact/picture/sync/ContactHandler.java)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It is not like I want to access use my Camera App for Contact App only, for every app it must working because default Camera is working fine and I have tested with these two permission but no result,  and Default Camera also has not used these two permission

Comment: What do you mean by "Default camera"? The app preinstalled on the phone??

Comment: Yes Preinstalled app, event not just preinstalled, I have tried with Camera app from Google Play Store it's also working fine

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `File`, use `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)` to get simply get the `OutputStream`.