# Android Camera Intent only shows stock camera instead of all camera apps

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am integrating taking photo into my app using existing installed camera apps. On my phone, there are some camera apps installed, but I can only see the one that shipped with the phone.

**Here is my code:**

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    File tempFile = // ....            
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "my_fileprovider", tempFile);

    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RC_CAMERA_RETURN);
}
```

**What I expected:**

The app will show a list of installed camera apps and the user can pick up one.

**My phone info**: Sony Xperia Z2 with the following installed camera apps

- Camera from Sony ( shipped with Z2) ----- Only see this one
- Camera ZOOM FX
- Retrica

Comment: can you please specify which app is not coming up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the target app you are referring to did not [register itself appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554600/android-how-to-register-my-app-as-camera-app) as camera app.

If you know exactly what app you want to open, you might specify that information in an [explicit Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to open that particular app. Otherwise the user has to pick one of the available apps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use to get app's manifest and get the Intent action and you can directly add action to the intent,
[check App to check manifest of any app installed in android link here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en)

That's How I solved same problem.