# Xamarin.Android Camera2 API Camera don`t appears in default apps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera2

I downloaded the sample Сamera2 API code to my device. In another app, I want to launch a third-party camera, but I can't select the one I downloaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554600/android-how-to-register-my-app-as-camera-app

Comment: it worked for me, but I wrapped it with application, the app appeared, but when I select it, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found solution for Xamarin.Android. I added above my CameraActivity page right near that Manifest String
[Activity (Label = "Camera2Basic", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

my Intent Filter which contains this code

[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault})]

This code write strings in Manifest, they needs for default intent call